# Converting a PNG buffer to a JPG in graphicsmagick in node

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

How do I convert a png buffer to a jpg without writing to a file?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359214/graphicsmagick-for-node-not-writing-the-whole-jpg

Comment: don't think you can do it without writing to a file...

Comment: use https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't write to a file?  What about a memory-mapped (transient) file?

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

```
var gm = require('gm')

// convert a buffer to a stream
gm(buffer, 'img.png')
.stream('jpg')
.pipe(outputStream);


// convert a buffer to a buffer
gm(buffer, 'img.png')
.toBuffer('PNG',function (err, buffer) {
   if (err) return handle(err);
   console.log('done!');
})
```

Comment: note: this doesn't seem to work with the latest version of graphicsmagick